# Explode data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-explode

I have data in the table which I wanted to explode

Input:

```
| Col 1    | Col 2    | Col 3   |
| -------- | ---------|---------|
| [A,B,C,D]| Value 1  | Value 2 |
```

Expected Output: The 'col 1' is exploded in the combination the [A,B,C,D].
The values 'col 1' can vary in length also the values are dynamic

```
| Col 1    | Col 2    | Col 3 |
| -------- | -------- |-------|
| [A,B]    | Value 1  |Value 2|
| [A,C]    | Value 1  |Value 2|
| [A,D]    | Value 1  |Value 2|
| [B,C]    | Value 1  |Value 2|
| [B,D]    | Value 1  |Value 2|
| [C,D]    | Value 1  |Value 2|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) on `Col 1` column then explode

```py
import itertools

df['Col 1'] = df['Col 1'].apply(lambda lst: list(itertools.combinations(lst, 2)))
out = df.explode('Col 1', ignore_index=True)
```

```
print(out)

    Col 1    Col 2    Col 3
0  (A, B)  Value 1  Value 2
1  (A, C)  Value 1  Value 2
2  (A, D)  Value 1  Value 2
3  (B, C)  Value 1  Value 2
4  (B, D)  Value 1  Value 2
5  (C, D)  Value 1  Value 2
```